# UILocalNotification not firing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uilocalnotification

I am *very* new to Cocoa Touch and Objective-C but I've gotten the pretty big points down and I am experimenting with the UIKit. I have a action linked to a button that changes a label and fires a UILocalNotification and this is the action method:

```
- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {
    self.LabelOne.text = @"WHAT UPPP!";
    self.NotifyOne.alertBody = @"Testtttttt";
    self.NotifyOne.alertAction = @"Got It.";
    self.NotifyOne.fireDate = nil;
}
```

There are no errors or warnings, but it's just not firing. Is there anything wrong with my action method?

**UPDATE**
Here is the App Delegate initialization that contains the `UILocalNotification`:

```
@interface LearnAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIButton *_ModifyLabelButton;
    UILabel *_LabelOne;
    UILocalNotification *_NotifyOne;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILocalNotification *NotifyOne;
```

Comment: Please post the part of your code where you actually schedule or alloc the `UILocalNotification`.

Comment: What's the IBOulet for? That is only if you want to connect it up with something. Also make both the property and the declaration the same name (both _NotifyOne or both NotifyOne).

Comment: Anyway this all seems broken with iOS 5.0. More or less...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are wanting it show without a schedule (eg. when you press a button) then either use `UIAlertView` or add `[application presentLocalNotificationNow:self.NotifyOne];` to your code.

**UPDATE**

Remove IBOutlet and make both declarations of UILocalNotification the same name. For example:

```
@interface LearnAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIButton *_ModifyLabelButton;
    UILabel *_LabelOne;
    UILocalNotification *NotifyOne;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILocalNotification *NotifyOne;
```

Remember to `synthesize` in your implementation (.m) file.

Also try this instead:

```
- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {
    self.LabelOne.text = @"WHAT UPPP!";
    NotifyOne = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (NotifyOne) {
        NotifyOne.alertBody = @"Testtttttt";
        NotifyOne.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Got It.", nil);
        NotifyOne.fireDate = nil;
        NotifyOne.soundName = nil;
        NotifyOne.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        [application presentLocalNotificationNow:NotifyOne];
        [NotifyOne release];
        NotifyOne = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you ever scheduling the alarm? Here is code I use to fire alarms.

```
UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (alarm) {
        alarm.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
        alarm.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
        alarm.alertBody = @"Test message...";       
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
        [alarm release];
    }
```

Comment: Where are you supposed to put this? Header or Implementation of the App Delegate?

Comment: It would be in your implementation wherever you want the notification to fire. It looks like putting it in your IBAction is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

A `UILocalNotification` isn't going to fire if you don't provide it with a `fireDate` and schedule it with your application instance. If you're trying to immediately present some sort of alert, perhaps you should try using `UIAlertView`.

Comment: Apple Documentation says that if `fireDate` is passed `nil` it will execute immediately.

Comment: Good to know, but it's not going to do anything if its not scheduled to fire.